# Where can I get algorithms pseudocode of algorithm C5.0 or C4.5?

Tags: machine-learning

I want to go through algorithm of C5.0 or C4.5
I want to know how does it works so that I can better predict where it would fetch better result.

Comment: I'd suggest you to use CART (and not such proprietary bullshit as Cx.x).

Answer (score 1):

I think nowhere. It is a proprietary stuff. Use CART - it is much better.